# Creating matrix in R

Tags: r, matlab

How to create this (matlab) matrix in R

```
ABC     =    {[1     1     3  ]   [4      5    6  ]
              [1     1     2  ]   [1      1    2  ]
              [1    32    2   ]   [2      3    1  ] };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `array` in `R`:

```
ABC <- array(c(1,1,1, 1,1,32, 3,2,2, 4,1,2, 5,1,3, 6,2,1), dim=c(3,3,2))

> ABC
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    3
[2,]    1    1    2
[3,]    1   32    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    1    1    2
[3,]    2    3    1
```

(assuming that I have your structure correct.  It's been decades since I last touched `matlab`.)

Comment: @Matthew_Lundberg, thanks. I think this will do the trick, I hope.